# python selenium webdriver.IE：Quick check to see if we have a W3C complaint brower

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

My environment：
Python 3.6.0

Selenium 3.3.1

IEDriverServer_x64_3.8.0

IE11

```
from selenium import web driver
Driver=we driver.Ie(‘C:\Program File\IE\IEDriverServer.exe’)
Driver.get(‘https://www.google.com’)
```

Then there is a error like this:
 [image]

(So sorry that I can’t use my cellphone to input all these words in error , so I get a screen shot...)

But when I use IEDriverServer_X64_3.4.0,It works well!
it really puzzled me,please help:How can I use the newest IEDRIVERSERVER?

Comment: Are you sure the question you posted looks like you expected?

Comment: Sorry~I am in a country where people can’t log in stackoverflow. So I have to ues my cellphone to ask a question, then use my PC to complete it. I change between my cellphone and PC for more than 10 times to complete my question. @EugeneS

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: @JeffC Trid but I can’t log in StackOverFlow on PC.So I input my code and get a screenshot to show the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code block you have used `’` instead of `'`

```
driver = webdriver.Ie(’C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEDriverServer.exe’)
```

This error can come from coping text from other source and paste into scripts.

- Replace `’` with `'` and add the `r` switch and argument type `executable_path` as follows:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\IEDriverServer.exe')
  ```
- Additionally, to maintain compatibility between the binaries, if you are using the Selenium client of version 3.x.y try to use IEDriverServer.exe of version 3.x.y.z only. So as you are using Selenium 3.3.1 use the IEDriverServer.exe v3.3.x only.
- Ensure that you are using the correct binaries of effective architecture. IEDriverServer_Win32_3.8.0 can be used in place of IEDriverServer_x64_3.8.0 but not the vice-versa.

Comment: So sorry，I input my code by my cellphone，so the“‘” is not the right one on my PC. I trid to use “’” and “r”， it doesn't work. The error is as same as before.

Comment: I change the code as your solution shows，but nothing changed…Also the same error

Comment: when I use IEDriverServer 3.4.0，it works well@DebanjanB

Comment: Updated my Answer. Let me know the status.

Comment: Please reduce the amount of formatting you are using in your answers. It makes them hard to read. There's no need to format "Automation Scripts", "IEDriverServer.exe", etc. as code and use all that bold. See [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362515/2386774).

Comment: @DebanjanB I updated my selenium to 3.8.1 and IEDriverServer to 3.8.0.They work well! Thank you for your advise!

Comment: @DebanjanB Done～Thank you again～

Comment: @JeffC A big _Thanks_ to you for all your time and effort to edit/prettify the Answers. However I would request you to look back the [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362515/is-this-formatting-overuse) as you are clearly _violating_ the rules by _downvoting_ . None of the Answers points towards downvoting for _formatting overuse_ as such.

Comment: @DebanjanB There is no comment in that thread or any other that I've seen that states that you can't downvote for excessive formatting. In fact, I saw at least a couple times people suggest that excessive formatting *should* be downvoted because of the formatting. You can see one such comment in the thread you linked.

Comment: @DebanjanB Having said that, I never downvoted any of your answers because of formatting... it was because of content. While the formatting made the answers hard to read, downvotes are (in my mind) to be used when the answer "is not useful" per the tooltip. I downvoted your answers because there was wrong information provided, bad advice/advice counter to best practices, etc. and at times because you went off on a tangent that had nothing to do with the question.